# onClick function is not executing

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener

I'm working on getting my onClickListener working but for some reason it is not executing.

I've looked through similar questions, but none of the solutions are working. The button's clickable property is true and my code similar to this in another file is working properly.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.goLogin);
System.out.print("made the button");

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(final View v) {
     System.out.println("x");
   }
});
```

"Made the button" is printing, but "x" is not.

Comment: what have you tried? what happened vs. what you expected?

Comment: why you using `System.out.println`? You should use `Log` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think final should be with View v.
Try replacing final.

```
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       System.out.println("x");
       }
    });
```